# Hide the badge number when it is 0 using React and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, badge

I am developing a Badge component. I want to hide the Bade when the number is 0.

I tried this on codesandbox. I am using invisible as a prop. This has a class "invisible". I am not sure how to apply this class when the batchContent is 0. I tried but it's not working.
Not sure if using useState would help. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Here is my link https://codesandbox.io/s/badgecomponent-ljdq25?file=/src/components/Badge.tsx

Comment: One option is to return `null` from a component in this condition. So something like
```
if (badgeContent === 0) {
  return null
}
```

inside your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just render it conditionally - display it only if `badgeContent` is greater than `0`.

```
{Number(badgeContent) > 0 && (
   <span className={`badgeContent`}>
      {displayValue}
   </span>
)}
```